# How to Unclone and Unprotect items programmatically in Sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I want to Unclone and Unprotect items in Sitecore.
There is an item.Clone() method available but I couldn't find one for Unclone or Unprotect.
Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For uncloning it's:

```
if (item.IsClone)
{
    var clone = new CloneItem(item);
    clone.Unclone();
}
```

For unlocking it's:

```
if (item.Locking.IsLocked() && item.Access.CanWrite())
{
    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        item.Locking.Unlock();
    }
}
```

And unprotecting:

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item.Appearance.ReadOnly = false;
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you. One question, is Unlocking an item the same as unprotecting it, as I need to unprotect the item.